# result object to arrayList

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

```
<lfm status="ok">
    <artists user="Ewout1" page="1" perPage="50" totalPages="36" total="1766">
        <artist>
        <name>Have Heart</name>
        <playcount>2582</playcount>
        <tagcount>0</tagcount>
        <mbid>e519e012-e1a3-4592-b3f6-5a16227ab654</mbid>
        <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Have+Heart</url>
        <streamable>1</streamable>
        <image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/36974461.jpg</image>
        <image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/36974461.jpg</image>
        <image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/36974461.jpg</image>
        <image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/36974461.jpg</image>
        <image size="mega">
    http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/36974461/Have+Heart+s+final+show+of+thei.jpg
        </image>
    </artist>
    ...
</lfm>
```

I have an httpservice that returns this xml-file. What I want to do is put all the names from the artists in one Arraylist. This is my code, but it doesn't work, and searches haven't helped me.

```
private var arArtists:ArrayList;
arArtists = event.result.artists.artist.name;
```

Comment: You could try looping through each name and adding them individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by ToddBFisher, you will have to iterate through your XMLList and add each item to the ArrayList.  XMLLists inherit directly from the base Object and has no direct inheritance relation to ArrayLists.

This block would work, but will be a point of contention based on the size of your data set.

```
var list:ArrayList = new ArrayList();
var name:XML;

for each(name in xml.artists.artist.name)
{
    list.addItem(name);
}
```

Best of luck!